# Angular - checkbox for string value of "true" or "false" gets checked always

Tags: html, angular, typescript, forms, angular2-directives

I am working with an Angular application and getting data from a database.
What gets returned is a string value, with different kinds of "values", some may be a string of JSON data, some may be just a string of texts, some is a string of boolean "true" or "false", however, it's still just a string.

And I have made changes so the type of input will change depending on what kind of string version it is.

for the "true" and "false", I made it so it now is a checkbox. The checkbox should be checked when it returns "true", and when unchecking, in the console, it now is a "false". But the checkbox is always checked

here are some code snippets

```html
<input class="form-check"
       type="checkbox"
       *ngIf="isBoolValue"
       [(ngModel)]="model.value"
       ng-checked="isBoolValue" />
```

here I am using both a ngModel and a ng-checked, however, in the form, the only thing that works when submitting is ngModel, to make a change in the database from true to false.
isBoolValue is just a boolean to check if this is true or false.

```js
getDataById(id: string) {
  this.dataService.getDataById(id)
    .subscribe(result => {
      this.model = result;
      if (this.model.value === 'true'
        || this.model.value === 'false') {
        this.isBoolValue = true;
      }
    });
}
```

Any idea how this could be done?

Make a checkbox unchecked if the string value is "false", right now it is always checked because its not true boolean value, just a string value with "true" or "false"

Comment: What is your problem? The checkbox always checked or intercept the change value?

Comment: The checkbox is always checked, im not really using boolean values, the value is still a string but with "true" or "false".

When unchecking a checked box with the string value of "true", it then gets the value "false", which is correct, then when getting the same data again, the checkbox is checked even if I get "false" back from the database.

Comment: you do that in the getDataById Observable.... if true or false you set always isBoolValue to true

Comment: Yes, it needs to be true because that is what makes the input into checkbox, otherwise it would be a textfield

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I made some new changes and now it works as expected.

in the ts file i changed from

```
getDataById(id: string) {
  this.dataService.getDataById(id)
    .subscribe(result => {
      this.model = result;
      if (this.model.value === 'true'
        || this.model.value === 'false') {
        this.isBoolValue = true;
      }
    });
}
```

To this

```
getDataById(id: string) {
  this.dataService.getDataById(id)
    .subscribe(result => {
      this.model = result;
      if (this.model.value === 'true') {
        this.model.value = true;
        this.isBoolValue = true;
      } 
      else if(this.model.value === 'false') {
        this.model.value = false;
        this.isBoolValue = true;
      }
    });
}
```

and in my html file

```
<input class="form-check"
       type="checkbox"
       *ngIf="isBoolValue"
       [(ngModel)]="model.value" />
```

Just removed the ng-checked.

I also changed the type on value, from `string` to `any`.

`value: any;` instead of `value: string;`

When doing this I was able to change the value to a boolean type and hence be able to work with real boolean values and not just string values

Comment: Set a type to any in Typescript is a bad practice...

Answer (score 1):

the issue come because isBoolValue is always set to true

an idea can be to cast the value return by your observable to a boolean
and use it in the ng-checked

```
getDataById(id: string) {
  this.dataService.getDataById(id)
    .subscribe(result => {
      this.model = result;
      if (this.model.value === 'true'
        || this.model.value === 'false') {
        this.model.value = (this.model.value === 'true');
        this.isBoolValue = true;
      }
    });
}

<input class="form-check"
       type="checkbox"
       *ngIf="isBoolValue"
       [(ngModel)]="model.value"
       ng-checked="model.value" />
```

Comment: Intresting idea, sadly it did not help my case.
Thank you for your input though :)